# How to make torch.utils.data.Subset inherit methods from customly defined torch.utils.data.Dataset?

Tags: inheritance, dataset, subset, torch

I have defined my custom torch Dataset with a method `normalize_features(self)`, which just normalizes the features. Later in the code, I use `torch.utils.data.random_split` to split my data into train and test. However, this will create a `Subset` class types.

Now, when I call `train_data.normalize_features()`, it will throw an error, since the `Subset` does not inherit from my poor custom Dataset class. On the other hand, if I call `train_data.dataset.normalize_features()`, which will access the original dataset, now I will get the whole dataset normalized, despite wanting just the train_data normalized.

Any suggestions how to make the `Subset` inherit my method? Or any neat hacks to go around this?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, no. I also think the standard answers on calling methods of parent's class wouldn't work either, since the parent of Subset is not my dataset, but the generic pytorch abstract dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I went around this by making the method into a function which takes the subset as an argument

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).